# Retrieving object values from within an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quick one regarding why I have to use the syntax I am using, the code I have below works but I don't understand exactly why...

```
var allQuestionsArray = [
    [{question: "This is question 1", answer: 0}],
    [{question: "This is question 2", answer: 3}], 
    [{question: "This is question 3", answer: 2}], 
    [{question: "This is question 4",answer: 1}]
    ]; 

for (i=0; i < allQuestionsArray.length; i++) {
    var question = allQuestionsArray[1][0].question;
    var possibleAnswers = allQuestionsArray[1][0].answer;
    document.getElementById("qnAsked").innerHTML = question;
    document.getElementById("answerChoices").innerHTML = possibleAnswers;
}
```

My query is why do I need to use "allQuestionsArray[1][0].question;" instead of "allQuestionsArray[1].question;" (or "allQuestionsArray[0][1].question;") to retrieve the question value for the second element within 'allQuestionsArray'?

I feel like one of the latter two should work and that my syntax must be wrong somehow but perhaps I'm just misunderstanding how this code functions. Any insights would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Because you've got two layers of `[ ]`. There's the outer brackets on the first and last line of the declaration, and then you've got `[ ]` around each object.

Comment: You've got an array, which contains lots of arrays, which each contain an object. So for instance `allQuestionsArray[1][0].question` accesses the first array within `allQuestionsArray`, and then the first child of the object within it.

Comment: Because that's how you set up your object-in-array-in-array structure...

Comment: Because you have an array of arrays (multi-dimensional array)

Comment: Also, why `[1]`? Wouldn't you want to use `[i]` instead...?!

Comment: @deceze my bad, should've changed to 'i' before posting... was using numbers in my code to test to see if each specific question was working first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an array of arrays. If you simply had and array of objects, your second option would work. However, you have an array of arrays that each contain one object. It's like the difference between this:

`var array = [ {} , {} , {} , {} , {} ];`

and this:

`var newAray = [ [{}] , [{}] , [{}] , [{}] ];`

You have to use the more complicated way of access for the second one because of the extra layer of wrapping around each element. for example, `array[1].question` might return correctly, but you have to use something different for the nested array.

`newArray[1][0].question`

This accesses the second element in the array, which is an array, and then the first element in this array, which is an object, and then accesses the `.question` property of the object.

Comment: Thanks Kai... the superfluous extra [...] around each object is what was confusing me, I knew there was something unnecessary there!

Answer (score 1):

You've got an array, which contains lots of arrays, which each contain an object. So for instance `allQuestionsArray[1][0].question` accesses the first array within `allQuestionsArray`, and then the first child of the object within it.

Comment: Thanks Mike, as I mentioned to Kai, was those superfluous extra sets of [...] around each object which had me confused. Appreciate the quick response...